# Is there a way to sort duplicates into a group that are found in an array using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array such as:

```
var aos = ["a","a","b","c","d"];
```

and I want to know if I can find duplicates of each index and store them into something such as an arraylist? For instance we start at:

`aos[0]`

That then checks to see if

`a`

is found, and it will keep running through the array taking all the elements with that value in index 0 storing them into a list (such as an arraylist or collection) and then removing them from the list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var uniq =_.uniq(aos)`

Or a long winded way (ES5) :

```
var uniq = aos.reduce(aos, function(memo, val) {
    if (!aos.some(function(elem) { return elem === val; })) {
         return memo.push(val);
    }
}, []);
```

And if you want to support ES3 then :

```
var uniq = [];
for (var i = 0, ii = aos.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var contains = false;
    for (var j = 0, jj < uniq.length; j < jj; j++) {
        if (uniq[j] === aos[i]) {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!contains) {
        uniq.push(aos[i]);
    }
}
```

Store duplicates in a new array:

```
var duplicates = _.select(aos, function(val) {
    var true = _.after(2, function() { return true; });
    return _.any(aos, function(elem) {
        return elem === val ? true() : false;    
    });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dTgvS/12/)

[`_.uniq`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#uniq), [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`_.any`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#any), [`_.select`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#select), [`_.after`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#after)

Comment: Does this hold all the duplicates? so when it takes both "a"'s from the example it will hold hold one of those duplicates in the " varuniq" array. It's kind of hard to explain, I can try to find more examples if needed.

Comment: @DennisMartinez you want to store all the duplicates aswell? This just strips the duplicates out of the array

Comment: Yes the duplicates are going to be used later one. I guess if you want to think of it like this it might work. Think of the first "a" being the parent in a tree, and the duplicates are it's children, so I need to leave the first instance of "a" and store the rest of the "a"'s into an array later to populate a table.

Comment: You... are freaking awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove duplicate items?, try this:

```
function unique_array(array) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
            if (array[i] === array[j]) {
                j = ++i;
            }
        }
        result.push(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < this.length; ++j) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) {
                j = ++i;
            }   
        }
        result.push(this[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

Array.prototype.duplicates = function() {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < this.length; ++j) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) {
                result.push(this[i]);
                j = ++i;
            }           
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// aos.unique() => a,b,c,d
// aos.duplicates() => a
```